# Which is the best way to skip characters before underscore ( _ ) in a string using c#

Tags: c#, string, filtering

Which is the best way to skip characters before underscore `_` in a string using c#?

eg:**case 1**  String contain `_`

```
string s="abc_defg"
```

I want to get defg to another string

**case 2**

some times string do not contain `_` . at that time i need to get the all string

eg.

```
s="defg"
```

In both case i want get "defg"  . Filtering only applied if there is an underscore in the string. How can i do that

Comment: @Null Pointer You can use also String.Split

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string s="abc_defg";
int ix = s.IndexOf('_');
s = ix != -1 ? s.Substring(ix + 1) : s;
```

using the ternary operator here is quite useless, better to write:

```
s = s.Substring(ix + 1);
```

directly, using the fact that `Substring` probably is optimized for the case index == 0

Is this what you want?

BUT someone has suggested using LINQ cannons, so

```
var temp = s.SkipWhile(p => p != '_').Skip(1);
s = temp.Any() ? new string(temp.ToArray()) : s;
```

In .NET 4.0 there is a new `string.Concat` method.

```
s = temp.Any() ? string.Concat(temp) : s;
```

(note that in general the LINQ way is slower and more complex to read)

I'll add the ultrakill: the Regular Expressions!!! There is a school of thought that anything can be done with Regular Expressions OR jQuery! :-)

```
var rx = new Regex("(?:[^_]*_)?(.*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var res = rx.Match(s).Groups[1].Value;
```

I won't even try to explain this beast to anyone, so don't ask. It's useless. (both the Regex and to ask :-) )

Comment: Hey, why you are using MY cannons? ;)

Comment: @sll because mine isn't loaded with blanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

I do not know how to define the best way but this works as long as there is only one underscore.

```
string s1 = "abc_defg";
string s2 = "defg";

Console.WriteLine( s1.Split('_').Last() );
Console.WriteLine( s2.Split('_').Last() );
```

If you need more flexibility you can take a look at regular expressions.

```
Regex.Replace(s1, "^.*_", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage LINQ [SkipWhile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx#Y0):

```
textValue.SkipWhile(c => c != separator)
         .Skip(1)
```

Final solution for both cases:

```
string textValue = "abc_defg";
char separator = '_';
string result = textValue.IndexOf(separator) >= 0 
                ? new String(textValue.SkipWhile(c => c != separator)
                                      .Skip(1)
                                      .ToArray())
                : textValue;
```

EDIT:

I'm right with xanatos comment, but anyway sometimes it is pretty interesting to find out different solutions :)

Comment: +1 because using LINQ here is so like using cannons against insects... :-)

Comment: @xanatos : take it easy ;) LINQ code looks pretty nice anyway ;)

Comment: @xanatos : This is obvious that LINQ does not return string, I believe OP know how to translate IEnumerable<char> into string

Answer (score 2):

simple function perhaps:

```
public string TakeStringAfterUnderscoreOrWholeString(string  input)
{
   var underscorePos = input.IndexOf("_");
   return underscorePos  == -1 ? input : input.Substring(underscorePos+1);
}
```

Live test: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=AVQO61388

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply use a string[] arr and split function for this purpose.

```
string[] arr=s.split('_');
string out=arr[arr.Length-1];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.But this question already answered .And what if there are more than one underscore in the string? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: in that case how to do u expect the output to be...for example for "qwe_etr_uit" what should be the output??

Comment: at that case the result should be etr_ui . He Jay , I already used other answer :D. So already solved the issue with the answer i marked as answer .Thanks for your effort